# How to shutdown/kill Spark Streaming application when one of the job fails

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a Spark streaming application. There are few times where one of the jobs fails due to some runtime exception. Spark marks the job as failed and continues to process the next streaming batch. Is there a parameter that I can set to notify Spark to kill the application (not to process next streaming batch) if one of the jobs fails? I am using Spark 1.4.1 on Standalone cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your program, you could:

1. throw an exception and bubble it up to the main, surrounding the main body in a try catch
2. put a `System.exit(0)` where you want. If your shutDownGracefully property is set to true, it will close gracefully ever spark process and end the program. [Here is a reference](https://metabroadcast.com/blog/stop-your-spark-streaming-application-gracefully)